# Yearling too quick?

Tags: bug

I was just awarded yearling on 9-14-2016
I was awarded it last on 12-15-2015

Isn't that less than a year?

[image: capture]

url to reproduce -> https://meta.superuser.com/users/20256/hogan?tab=activity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have been a member for 6 years. For the Yearling badge, you also need to earn 200 reputation **per year**.

This means that you will get the badge awarded whenever you earn 200 more reputation, up until you've received the badge an amount of times equal to the amount of yours you've been a member (currently 6).

Comment: This is a very nice answer but it has nothing to do with my question.  A yearly badge should be awarded once a year.  This was awarded after 9 months.  That is clearly a bug.

Comment: @Hogan It actually has *everything* to do with your question, is not a bug and completely by design. But, if you don't trust me, feel free to wait for a different answer, which will be wrong, but maybe will be more to your liking ;)

Comment: Your answer would make sense if I just went over 400 reputation in the last few days, but that is not the case.  I've been at over 400 since the last yearly.  So there is a bug (or a change to how things work which makes this look strange).

Comment: @Hogan According to http://superuser.com/users/20256/hogan?tab=reputation you received 1 upvote yesterday, bringing you from 399 to 404 reputation. So that adds up, unless I'm missing something. Your total is relevant here and you need 200 for every year that is taken into consideration. The relevant time differences are not measured between now and the time you last earned the badge, but between now and the time you registered on the site. If you would earn another 200 rep today, you would get another Yearling badge within 24h.

Comment: wow that makes sense but can you see the mystery -- why isn't the +5 points visible on the link I posted in my question.

Comment: @Hogan I can definitely see that. The question has come up multiple times all over the network, as far as I remember :) The link you posted only shows your own activity on the site.

Comment: I actually just figured that out -- I was looking at the "meta" site not the "main" site.  I did get a yearly message for both, but then later one went away -- so maybe that is how I went wrong.